# Why pressing BACK closes both the Activities?

Tags: android

It never happened to me before.

From one Activity (MyActivity) I start another Activity (MainActivity):

```
Intent in = new Intent(MyActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(in)
```

but why if I press BACK on MainActivity bot MyActivity and MainActivity are closed?

```
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
      <!--You need it for the Service to work-->
    <service android:name=".MyService"></service>
    <activity android:name="zirco.ui.activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/ApplicationName"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Anything relevant in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: Can you post some more code specially manifest

Comment: It does not crash... I have checked the logs :-(((

Comment: @LisaAnne Have you considered my answer? I'm pretty sure it'll solve your problem, open and shut case :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the context to start the activity, assuming that the code is inside `MyActivity.java`, then try:

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
this.startActivity(in);
```

Or you could try (if the code is inside an event for example...):

```
Context ctx = this;
//stuff
Intent in = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
ctx.startActivity(in);
```

Comment: MyActivity.this accesses the containing class instance from an inner class.  No need to declare a Context variable.  She is already doing that correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure whether you have to, but you can override onBackPressed() method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext() ,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the way `zirco.ui.activities.MainActivity` handles back button and the way you launch it.

Your manifest doesn't specify launch modes for the activity, so it uses the `standard` mode: new activity is added to the activity stack of the current task.

So far so good, but `zirco.ui.activities.MainActivity` calls `.moveTaskToBack()` as part of [it's back button handling logic](https://code.google.com/p/zirco-browser/source/browse/trunk/src/org/zirco/ui/activities/MainActivity.java?r=466#1492) and that makes the whole task -- including `MyActivity` -- to go to the back of the activity stack.

So, your best option is to either declare the attribute `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for `zirco.ui.activities.MainActivity` in your manifest or set the corresponding `Intent` flag programmatically:

```
Intent in = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(in);
```

Of course, you can also modify `zirco`'s code to use `super.onBackPressed()` instead of `moveTaskToBack()`, but I guess they had their reasons for pushing back the whole task.